# Application working on most of the devices but not on some

Tags: android, debugging, compatibility

My Application works all good but for some users a functionality isn't working. How to look after this, when the application is working fine for me and most of the users and not for some. How to debug it?

Comment: What is the problem you facing to your app? i mean it's not install or not working (crashing),Versions, device config . what it is?

Comment: same android version?

Comment: @MD , Manish, I have updated the question.

Comment: you should check this: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a bug tracking tool. I am using this one, it's really easy to use: [splunk mink](https://mint.splunk.com/) but there are also others like instabug, appsee or others.

The deal with such tracking tools is that you get live data from the app usage, errors, crashes and other useful information you can use to improve your app.

Comment: Moataz from Instabug here.

@Gauraw, Actually you can use Instabug for this use-case, you'll allow users to report their problems as well as collect detailed crash reports when things go wrong. Let me know if you need help with that.

Tim, thanks for the mention :)

Comment: Hey moataz, can I monitor anything about my application if I use instabug?

Comment: It's mainly crash reporting that you'll get automatically reported from the app. You'll also allow your users to report issues manually. We don't provide analytics if that's what you're talking about. LMK if you need anymore details.